# Товарный чек

Tags: pascal

Выдает ошибку. Как сделать правильно самый простой магазинный чек? Я новичок)

```
program check;
var cena, sum, name, qua: real;
begin
 writeln('Введите название покупки ');
 readln(name);
 write('Введите цену единицы ');
 readln(cena);
 write('Введите количество купленого товара ');
 readln(qua);
 sum:=cena*qua;
 writeln('Сума ',name, sum:5:2,'руб.');
 writeln('Спасибо за покупку')
end.
```

Comment: Какую ошибку? Что конкретно не работает? Где входные данные?

Comment: (5 строка) Ошибка времени выполнения: Входная строка имела неверный формат.

Comment: Покажите входные данные

Comment: Условие? Если да, то "Ввести название, цену еденицы и количество купленого товара. Вывести чек - сообщение о б суме к оплате и сообщение "Спасибо за покупку"."

Comment: ...

Вы можете дать входные данные? (То, что вы вводите на обработку руками)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я думаю переменная `name` у Вас должна быть типа `string`:

```
...
program check;
var cena, sum, qua: real;
var name: string;
...
```

А ругается потому что Вы наверняка вводите в название покупки текст, а ожидается вещественное число.

Comment: P.S. А сума входит в цену покупки? :-)

Comment: Да, все вышло... Спасибо большое)

Answer (score 0):

Надо написать проверку ввода не коректных данных.